# CouchDB 2.0 - How to autoincrement keys in a View?

Tags: view, key, couchdb, auto-increment

In CouchDB 2.0, I'm trying to create an ordered list as the keys from a View, but it doesn't work.

My code for the View document:

```
var i = 0;
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === "comment") {    
    emit(i++, doc.webpages);
  }
}
```

The result is that all keys are equal to 0. How can I make it so that each document gets an autoincremented key?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why you want to do this/ how you want to use this? You can't do it as designed because no scope is kept outside of your function. Also, any given comment isn't guaranteed the same 'i' value over multiple runs of the view.

Comment: @sarwar I just thought it would be easy to do, but you explained now why it isn't, *there is no scope outside of function(doc)*. It makes sense, but are you sure about it? I wanted to create an ordered list, but maybe I can simply retrieve a list with the View and use `?startkey=x` and `endkey=x+3` to get index slices. BTW, I'm still learning CouchDB, so for now I don't really have a project, I'm just playing with it

Comment: I've added an answer that shows my typical approach to using keys. Multi-part keys are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequential ID probably isn't the best choice for most real applications. For example, if you were to build a commenting system I would approach it like this (there's a [similar example](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html) in the couch docs):

Comments would be docs with a structure like this:

```
{
    "_id": "comment_id",
     "parent":"comment_id, or article_id if a top level comment"
     "timestamp" : "iso datetime populated by the server",
     "user_id": "the person who wrote the comment",
     "content": "content of the comment"
}
```

To display all the top level comments of a given parent (either article or parent comment), you could use a view like this:

```
def function(doc){
  emit([doc.parent, doc.timestamp, doc.user_id], doc._id)
}
```

To query this efficiently, you'd could use the following [query options](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) to grab the first twenty:

```
{
    "startkey": ["parent_id"],
    "endkey": ["parent_id", {}],
    "limit": 20,
    "skip": 0,
    "include_docs": true
}
```

The comments will automatically be sorted by the date they were posted because the view is ordered by [parent, datetime, and then user]. You don't have the pass a value for anything other than parent with your key for benefit from this.

Another thing of note is by not passing the content of the comment to the view and instead using include_docs, your index will remain as slim as possible.

To expand on this:

- If you want to show replies to a base comment, you can just change
  the start and end keys to that comment's id.
- If you want to show the next 20 comments, just change skip to 20.
- If you want more comments shown initially, just up the limit value.

In answer to your comment, if you had an array or parents in your document like:

```
"parents" : ["a100", "a101", "a102"]
```

Everything else would remain the same, except you would emit a row for each parent.

```
def function(doc){
  doc.parents.map( function (parent){
    emit([doc.parent, doc.timestamp, doc.user_id], doc._id)
  });
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! You're right, I can simply build the list based on a document's property. But in regard to index, can I make another question? Suppose the same comment appears in 3 posts (I know, not a blog example), if I use an array for the field `parent` like this: `"parent" : [4,70,103]`, would the index in this array be efficient (if I do a View to emit this field) if I want to retrieve all comments that belong to `post_id `70? Would you suggest a better solution in this case? And how did you learn CouchDB, only through the documentation?

Comment: The approach would be the same, except you would emit multiple rows from a single comment doc. I updated my answer. I've learned couch by using it. The docs are sufficient, but fairly simplistic. This site has some great questions and answers on more advanced usage. Most of the challenge is understanding how to use map-reduce well. With CouchDB 2.0 that's less of an issue since there are other query methods.